Azure Kubernetes Service ClusterIssuer DnsNames
I have kubernetes running in azure (aks). I want to create some certificates using cert manager. So i configured the cluster issuer as follow:
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: test-cluster-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: <my-email>
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: test-cluster-issuer
        solvers:
      - selector:
          dnsZones:
            - "my-domain.com"
        dns01:
          route53:
            region: eu-west-1
            accessKeyID: "AWSID"
            secretAccessKeySecretRef:
              name: route53-secret
              key: secretAccessKey


so far al good, i tried to create a Certificate kind.
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: istio-cert
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  secretName: istio-cert
  dnsNames:
    - dns1.example.com
    - dns2.example.com
    - dns3.example.com
    - dns4.example.com
    - dns5.example.com
    - dns6.example.com
    - dns7.example.com
    - dns8.example.com
    - dns9.example.com
    - dns10.example.com
    - dns11.example.com
  issuerRef:
    name: test-cluster-issuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    group: cert-manager.io

when i apply the certificate yaml, i go to check the kubectl challenges and all goes well, all the dns are valid and registered, the describe on the certificate shows the expire date and renew and all the dns names i passed in the yaml file. But when i hit on some of those url (random everytime) some of them have a certificate attached, others no.
Am i doing something wrong here? because i am really confused why every time i run the certificates, the ssl cert is working on random dns and not others.
I hope i explained properly the issue and ifnot and you need more details, please do not hesitate to ask for more details. Thank you so much
UPDATE: For testing purpose i tried to change the solver from http-01 to a dns01. Same outcome. In my Route53 i see the TXT records created for each dnsName in the certificate, the challenge is solved and certificate is valid, but when i browse to the url, i still get the connection not secure.
cert manager logs shows the following:
controller.go:161] cert-manager/challenges "msg"="re-queuing item due to optimistic locking on resource" "key"="istio-system/route-53-certificate-b8dl7-3369750843-4049146426" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on challenges.acme.cert-manager.io \"route-53-certificate-b8dl7-3369750843-4049146426\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again"
E0711 23:43:30.844837       1 controller.go:234] cert-manager/challenges "msg"="challenge in work queue no longer exists" "error"="challenge.acme.cert-manager.io \"route-53-certificate-b8dl7-3369750843-4049146426\" not found"
E0711 23:43:35.514257       1 controller.go:234] cert-manager/challenges "msg"="challenge in work queue no longer exists" "error"="challenge.acme.cert-manager.io \"route-53-certificate-b8dl7-3369750843-4049146426\" not found"

those logs happened after the certificate was issued.

what are the logs of Ingress Gateway and Cert-Manager saying?

@Arko thank you for your answer. I did some changes to the Cluster issuer to move away from the http-01 solver to a dns01. The challenge get resolved and the TXT records are added to my route53, but not certificate for the dnsNames. And the logs shows this: Operation cannot be fulfilled on challenges.acme.cert-manager.io \"route-53-certificate-b8dl7-3369750843-4049146426\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again"

@Arko sorry mate,  i just updated my post with the logs and latest configuration
